# Convert Integer to Float in Elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp, division, floating-point-conversion

I am having trivial problems converting integer division to a floating point solution in Emacs Lisp 24.5.1.

```
(message "divide: %2.1f" (float (/ 1 2)))
"divide: 0.0"
```

I believe this expression is first calculating 1/2, finds it is 0 after truncating, then assigning 0.0 to the float.  Obviously, I'm hoping for 0.5.
What am I not seeing here?  Thanks

Answer (score 12):

The `/` function performs a floating-point division if at least one of its argument is a float, and an integer quotient operation (rounded towards 0) if all of its arguments are integers. If you want to perform a floating-point division, make sure that at least one of the arguments is a float.

```
(message "divide: %2.1f" (/ (float 1) 2))
```

(or of course if they're constants you can just write `(/ 1.0 2)` or `(/ 1 2.0)`)

Many programming languages work this way.

Comment: Thank you so much!  As long as one of them is a float, the result is a float.  I knew that, but learning Lisp had me hypnotized in a way.  Thanks

Comment: The Elisp manual, node [Arithmetic Operations](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Arithmetic-Operations.html), explains this.